# How to deploy database on linux

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a small asp.net core website that I push to my server via jenkins. Jenkins does `git checkout` and then `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run`. It works for the website, but I added `entity framework` and I'm a little confused. How exactly do I move my local database to the server? Or should I create one on the server and then reference it?

I have one mssql database on `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, but when I run the server and try to go to a page which gets data from the database I get `500 Internal Server Error`.

I would like to have one local db for testing and one on the server, but I just can't wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: And why is this tagged under c#

Comment: Maybe you are right. I fixed it.

Comment: c# core can run in linux now.

Comment: @Christian4423 Yes I know. I have a running website. The question is how to deploy a database.

Comment: That comment was @Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in development, you should write a init script for your database. This will create all the required stuff your application needs.

So in linux...

Install the MySQL, get the users set up, and init the database.

In your application...
Provide the connection string for the DB installed in Linux.

I am not running my app in c# but this is similar to my node app. That is what I do. I develop in windows with Postgres. Then my prod is on a GoDaddy Linux cloud server and I have Postgres installed in that. When I do my git pull for the latest, I don't have to change much because of the .env file for my environment variables.